# Best way to display notifications in Opera v15 extension

Tags: opera, add-on, web-notifications

I have a chrome extension that I adapted to the Opera. Fortunately, all the features of my chrome extension worked well in Opera 15 without many changes. However, my extension uses the `webkitNotifications` to notify the result of the context menu click. It seems that the `web notifications` doesn't work in Opera extensions.

```
var notification = webkitNotifications.createNotification('icon_32.png','My extension title','Notification text');
notification.show();
setTimeout(function(){notification.cancel();}, 5000);
```

In this case, what is the best way to notify the user when the context menu is clicked? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`webKitNotifications.createHTMLNotification` [has been deprecated](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/desktop_notifications.html). New suggested way to create notifications is [in draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/notifications/) currently and [not many browsers have implemented it](http://caniuse.com/#feat=notifications).

In the meantime, I'd like to suggest to find another way to notify the user.

Comment: Well, what would you suggest specifically?

Comment: @afazolo Perhaps, something like [GMail Notifier](https://addons.opera.com/en/extensions/details/google-mail-notifier/)?